# How to find Automation_Id's using pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have java application. I want to find automation_id's for each control. I used print_control_identifiers() and dump_tree(). But, it took lot of time (more that 2 hours).Is there any possible way to get automation_id's within in small time? Also, with my application after clicking on button one window is opened. How can I find automation_id's for this window only?

Answer (score 1):

use Inspect.exe to find automation id's of any control